# Mac OS X Terminal: I repeatedly get error message "-bash: .DS_Store: command not found" in the terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

Yesterday I was trying to get .DS_Store files to be globally ignored by git.

I must have entered some command incorrectly because now every time I launch terminal or use the `cd` command, I get six lines of `-bash: .DS_Store: command not found`, like so:

```
[11:28:30] [~]$ cd Projects/
-bash: .DS_Store: command not found
-bash: .DS_Store: command not found
-bash: .DS_Store: command not found
-bash: .DS_Store: command not found
-bash: .DS_Store: command not found
-bash: .DS_Store: command not found
[11:28:33] [Projects]$
```

Obviously, DS_Store is not supposed to be a command.

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I don't remember exactly every command I ran.  I was googling, and trying stuff.
I know I did execute the commands found [here](http://antoniolorusso.com/2009/03/09/ignore-ds_store-forever-in-git/).

`git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore`

`echo .DS_Store >> ~/.gitignore`

**EDIT 2:**
I figured it out.  Answer provided below.

Comment: What steps did you take to get git to ignore `.DS_Store` files?

Comment: @Pitto No. Please don't suggest that. The question is perfectly on-topic here. If a question about an Apple product is on topic for Super User as defined in the the FAQ, then it should stay on Super User.

Comment: What is the content of your `~/.bashrc` and `~/Project/.git/config` file? Did you create a `.gitignore` file? Show them all please.

Comment: What does `history` show? Can you tell us what you did using the history output? Did you ever change `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
At some point I ran `echo .DS_Store >> ~/.rvmrc` a couple times.
My .rvmrc file looked like this:

```
export rvm_path="/Users/myname/.rvm"
.DS_Store
.DS_Store
```

I removed the two `.DS_Store` lines and everything is behaving properly.